# Xamarin iOS NFC Session is invalidated unexpectedly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nfc, custom-renderer

Have a Xamarin forms project and trying to hook in NFC reading to the app. Currently plumbing in the iOS native side of things. I've setup all the provisioning and options on the apple portal side of things and i've added the following to the entitlements:

```
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
   <array>
   <string>NDEF</string>
   </array>
 </dict>
```

Also added to the info.plist:

```
<key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
<string>NFC tag to read NDEF messages into the application</string>
```

The code i've got for my native dependency for iOS is as follows:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(RFIDScannerHelper))]
namespace MyProject.Mobile.Platform.iOS
{
public class RFIDScannerHelper : IRFIDScannerHelper
{        
    public bool hasRFID()
    {
        return true;
    }

    NFCNdefReaderSession Session;

    public void ScanRFID(Action<string> act, VisualElement el)
    {
        NFChecker nfchecker = new NFChecker();
        Session = new NFCNdefReaderSession(nfchecker, null, false);
        Session?.BeginSession();
    }       
}

public class NFChecker : NSObject, INFCNdefReaderSessionDelegate
{
    public Action<string> nfcFoundAction;

    public void DidDetect(NFCNdefReaderSession session, NFCNdefMessage[] messages)
    {
        foreach (NFCNdefMessage msg in messages)
        {
            if (msg.Records.Count() > 0)
            {
                nfcFoundAction.Invoke(new NSString(msg.Records[0].Payload, NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
            }
        }         
    }

    public void DidInvalidate(NFCNdefReaderSession session, NSError error)
    {
        var readerError = (NFCReaderError)(long)error.Code;
        if (readerError != NFCReaderError.ReaderSessionInvalidationErrorFirstNDEFTagRead &&
            readerError != NFCReaderError.ReaderSessionInvalidationErrorUserCanceled)
        {
        }            
    }
}
}
```

When this runs it all seems to fire correctly but on start of session it goes straight to the DidInvalidate method in the ReaderDelegate and the error says "Session is invalidated unexpectedly".

Can anyone tell me what I could be missing out?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried the xamarin provided sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios11/NFCTagReader/). But I also receive the exact same error "Session is invalidated unexpectedly". I've mucked around with our provisioning but no combination changes this error. Has anyone even got the xamarin sample to work?

Comment: Did you enable the  NFC Tag Reading capability in your provisioning file and use that file when installing this app to your device?

Comment: Have got that setup. Thanks

Comment: You code looks good and it should work if all the configuration has been set up. Can you try the official sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios11/NFCTagReader/) to see if it works on your side?

Comment: I have the same problem with the offial app... What could I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@matt, it's a Visual Studio 2019 error. You should select the Entitlements.plist in your project settings, but you are not able because the "entry" where you should insert the path is always disabled. I have reported the problem

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752711/xamarinios-i-cant-set-entitlements.html